# GET data from SharePoint on-premise and POST data to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom, sharepoint-clientobject

I need to GET data from SharePoint Server 2019 (On-premise) list and then I need to add that data to the SharePoint Online list using CSOM.

I have found the below link to get data from SharePoint Server (On-premise) list.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-client-object-modal-csom/

I have found below link to add data to SharePoint Online list.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-a-list-item-in-sharepoint-using-csomannouncement-list

Is that correct way or do I need prefer another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you just need list data without any version history or created/modified user and time stamps - you can export the SharePoint on-premise list to excel and use this excel file to create/import a new list in SharePoint Online.

Other options are to

1. Use Microsoft's "SharePoint Migration Tool" to migrate content - this is a free tool provided by Microsoft - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool
2. use CSOM code in a VS application as per the links you have - note that you don't need to create 2 separate applications for it, just create one app and create separate instances of the ClientContext for SP on-prem and SP online
3. use PnP PowerShell to get all list items and then loop over each item and create each item in target SPO site **OR** use SharePoint Powershell module to do the same. Here is an example of a script that migrates documents but with some minor modification you can get it to work with list data - https://github.com/alimughalx/CopySharePointFilesWithMetaDataAndVersionHistory